# Python in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I am new to Docker so I am sorry for such an easy question.

I am building a docker container which is built on top of a image which is built on ubuntu:vivid image.
When executing my script within the container I am getting an error:

```
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
```

How can I solve this?
When I try to run `apt-get install python` in my Docker file:

```
FROM my_image # based on ubuntu:vivid

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3

ENV PATH /:$PATH

COPY file.py /

CMD ["python", "file.py", "-h"]
```

I get:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libexpat1 libffi6 libmagic1 libmpdec2 libssl1.0.0 libpython3.4-minimal
  mime-support libsqlite3-0 libpython3.4-stdlib python3.4-minimal
  python3-minimal python3.4 libpython3-stdlib dh-python python3 file
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&   apt-get install -y python3' returned a non-zero code: 100
make: *** [image] Error 1
```

EDIT: added Dockerfile content

Comment: apt-get install python or try to find python executable in ur machine and add to $PATH???

Comment: Maybe you just use the [official python docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)?

Comment: @cricket_007 Since mine is already based on a different image I can't do that

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile contents. Simply running `apt-get` from the container's shell [isn't preferred](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Comment: can you try `apt-get -y update`

Comment: I have now updated the question to show my docker contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have similar issue with some Linux distribution: "[Why am I getting authentication errors for packages from an Ubuntu repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75565/5470)"

In all cases, the usual sequence of command to install new packages is:

```
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get install -yqq \
    git \
    python \
    ...
```

The [OP Ela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253620/ela) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052659/python-in-docker-container/35053944#comment57867979_35053944):

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    git \
    python \
    ...
```

Comment: I tried your approach and then got `Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&  apt-get install -  git  python' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: @Ela OK, I have edited the answer accordingly, adding the parameters `-yq` and `-yqq` which should allow you to be in non-interactive mode.

Comment: This worked, the -yq for update is unnecessary. Moreover, this can also be achieved by `install -y --force-yes`, you can update your answer if you want to include that. I don't know which way is more desirable

Answer (score 1):

You are installing python3 and then you use the executable of python, I had the same issue and I have resolved using python3.

Try changing your last line of your Dockerfile :

instead of 
`CMD ["python", "file.py", "-h"]`

try :
`CMD ["python3", "file.py", "-h"]`